# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)

Tags: angular, service

[[There are the service.ts, app.module.ts, an the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpqd3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyR2D.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvKcm.png)

I have this problem. i tried to importing the services in providers (without providedIn in the injectable), importing HttpClientModule in the app.module.ts, using providedIn: 'root' in the @Injectable and the error remain. Do you know what can i do?

Comment: i'm not a native English speaker so is possible that i made mistakes lol, hope that you understand

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put decorator @Injectable before you declaring your class (service for this case)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: ‘root’
})
export class RegisterService {…}
```